# user can not login in laravel 9 on server

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-9

The user is created correctly in the database but does not log in.
I use `Auth::loginUsingId($id);` this and `Auth::login($user);`
but the user does not log in.

everything is good locally but on the server doesn't work.
Does anyone know the problem?

`laravel9`

Comment: perhaps it is a session problem (potentially cookie issue)

Comment: Can you post your `User`  model? Does it extend `Authenticable`?

Comment: @lagbox I use a file driver and the session file has all permissions.

Comment: @IGP yes in the `User` model use `Authenticable`. But the problem remains

Comment: those things don't have to do with cookies